# python/multiprocessing: howto simplify "def" fields

Tags: python, multiprocessing, function

The script below simply counts from 0-9 using multiprocessing where Thread-1 counts even numbers and Thread-2 counts even numbers.  Note that the only difference in the workers themselves is the initial x value of 0 and 1.  Is there a way to simplify this rather than typing the same code over and over?  not a big deal for 2 thread but having lets way, 16 processes with (0-16) for each of the different start values, this gets very redundant.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker1(name):
    x = 0
    print name, 'starting...'
    while x < 10:
            print x
            x+=2
    print name, 'complete!'

def worker2(name):
    x = 1
    print name, 'starting...'
    while x < 10:
            print x
            x+=2
    print name, 'complete!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wa = Process(target=worker1, args=('Thread-1',))
    wb = Process(target=worker2, args=('Thread-2',))

    wa.start()
    wb.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `x` as an argument to `worker`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(x):
    name = mp.current_process().name
    print name, 'starting...'
    while x < 10:
            print x
            x+=2
    print name, 'complete!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_procs = 2
    procs = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=(x,)) for x in range(num_procs)]
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

You do not have to pass `name` as an argument; `multiprocessing` gives each process a name accessible with `mp.current_process().name`. If you really want a custom name, set the name with  `mp.Process(target=worker, name='custom name', ...)`. The custom name will then be accessible from within the `worker` with `` `mp.current_process().name ``.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the initial value as well as the steps and other variables to the worker:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker(name, initial, step=2):
    x = initial
    print name, 'starting...'
    while x < 10:
            print x
            x += step
    print name, 'complete!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wa = Process(target=worker1, args=('Thread-1', 0))
    wb = Process(target=worker2, args=('Thread-2', 1))

    wa.start()
    wb.start()
```